# Problems with WebAPI Routing

Tags: routes, webapi

I have several routes defined in the WebAPIConfig

```
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "RecordObject",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{objectId}",
            defaults: new { action = "List", objectId = RouteParameter.Optional });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "RecordString",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{ids}",
            defaults: new { action = "GetRecordsByIds", ids = RouteParameter.Optional });

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{id}/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

And I am using Postman to test the calls with some success but not all:

1. https://localhost:44339/api/records/List - WORKS FINE
2. https://localhost:44339/api/Records/GetRecordsByIds/LEECO-99HIS-00000-0MSFN - NO GOOD

Below are the methods:

```
    [HttpGet]
    //[Route("~/api/Records/list/{objectId}")]
    public async Task<List<Records>> List(ObjectId objectId)
    {}
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("GetRecordsById")]
    //[Route("~/api/Records/GetRecordsById/{Ids}")]        
    public async Task<JObject> GetRecordsByIds(string Ids)
    {}
```

As you can see I am attempting several approaches and not being successful. I could use some pointers and advice if available.

Answer (score 1):

Update: so I am still not positive this is the best approach, and I am open to any suggestions. But I made some changes which were inspired  by some searches on StackOverflow. I wanted to share them and possibly help someone else.

I made the following additions:

```
    [ActionName("GetRecordsByIds")]
    [Route("~/api/Records/GetRecordsByIds/{ids}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<JObject> GetRecordsByIds(string Ids){}
```

This appears to have resolved the issue. I am still open to opinions and suggestions. Writing good code is the objective, not just finding solutions without the understanding.